# Batch file - get variable as a string from Windows environment

Tags: php, batch-file

In Windows system variable I have the following variable

x = 123
Data_123 = ddd:

How do I get this variable as a string from batch filet

So at the end I want to get the variable like 
"Data"_%x%   and I will get the value ddd

How can I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set x=123
set data_123=hello
echo !data_%x%!
```

(there is [another method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43525134/2152082) without delayed expansion:

```
call echo %%data_%x%%%
```